# How can I disable blink ng-repeat of AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to show some repeated object AFTER receiving submitted query by AngularJS.
When I just see the following page without any submitting query, ng-repeat will render one ng-repeat's part of div with no result(thus empty). Why does this occur and how can I disable to show the empty result rendering?

- html

code

```
<form ng-submit="doSearch()" ng-keyup="doSearch()" name="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="<%= t('.placeholder') %>" ng-model="query" required>
  <input type="submit" class='button postfix' value="<%= t('.register') %>" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
</form>

<div ng-repeat="result in results">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <p ng-bind-html="result.contentSnippet"></p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="/#" target="_blank">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- controller

code

```
google.load "feeds", "1"

kindlers = angular.module("kindlers", [ "ngSanitize" ])

findFeeds = ($scope)->
  google.feeds.findFeeds $scope.query, (result) ->
    console.log $scope.query   
    if $scope.query == "undefined" || result.error
      $scope.results = undefined
    else
      $scope.results = result.entries 
    $scope.$apply()

@mainCtrl = ($scope, $http) ->
  console.log($scope.results)
  $scope.doSearch = ->
    google.setOnLoadCallback findFeeds($scope)
```

- JavaScript(converted from the above CoffeeScript)

code is below. console.log($scope.results); shows "undefined".

```
(function() {
  var findFeeds, kindlers;

  google.load("feeds", "1");

  kindlers = angular.module("kindlers", ["ngSanitize"]);

  findFeeds = function($scope) {
    return google.feeds.findFeeds($scope.query, function(result) {
      console.log($scope.query);
      if ($scope.query === "undefined" || result.error) {
        $scope.results = void 0;
      } else {
        $scope.results = result.entries;
      }
      return $scope.$apply();
    });
  };

  this.mainCtrl = function($scope, $http) {
    console.log($scope.results);
    return $scope.doSearch = function() {
      return google.setOnLoadCallback(findFeeds($scope));
    };
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: @Oledje, above is the controller's code.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the $results object to undefined ever. Initialize it as an empty array and when you have no results, set it back to an empty array...
$scope.results = [];

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your controller that results is totally empty. You could initialise it like this: `$scope.results = [];`

Comment: @gipcompany Your controller can inherit this value (`$scope.results`) from the parent controller.

Comment: @emilioicai, $scope.results right after mainCtrl showed undefined.

Comment: @Oledje, should I rename results in this case? I don't think this controller exists only one so it doesn't inherit any value from any controller though.

Comment: Just try to set value of this property to empty array ('[]') at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

How about ng-show="result.length > 0'

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$scope.results` to `{}` and default it to `{}` on error instead of undefined.

```
google.load "feeds", "1"

kindlers = angular.module("kindlers", [ "ngSanitize" ])

findFeeds = ($scope)->
  google.feeds.findFeeds $scope.query, (result) ->
    console.log $scope.query   
    if $scope.query == "undefined" || result.error
      $scope.results = {}
    else
      $scope.results = result.entries 
    $scope.$apply()

@mainCtrl = ($scope, $http) ->
  $scope.results = {}
  console.log($scope.results)
  $scope.doSearch = ->
    google.setOnLoadCallback findFeeds($scope)
```

Comment: This is not necessary, check this example, the div with the ng-repeat directive is not shown when the list is empty: http://plnkr.co/edit/P11PSafTahTciBvbuwHW?p=preview

Comment: @Alexander, I added ng-show="results" but I got the same result.

Comment: Thanks philippd, good to know.  I changed my answer @gipcompany